# In django, can you load a django app into the python interpreter like in rails?

Tags: python, django

In django, can you load a django app into the python interpreter like in rails?

i.e. does django have: irb

?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you mean `python manage.py shell` ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a more powerful Python shell to use with Django, you can look at [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/). Just install it and the `python manage.py shell` will use ipython instead of the default one.

Check the IPython website to see the interesting features it brings.

Comment: Ah! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it can be via `python manage.py shell`, it's also useful to look into the django-extensions plugin for extra functionality such as `shell_plus` which provides all of the database interactions for the shell environment as welll.